# python list of dicts - extract key-val of lists

Tags: python, list-comprehension

With a list of dicts like below

```
a = [{'a': 1, 'b': [{'c': [1, 2, 3], 'd': 4}, {'c': [5, 6, 1], 'd': 7}]}, {'a': 2, 'b': [{'c': [2, 3, 4], 'd': 5}, {'c': [7, 6, 1], 'd': 8}]}]
```

need to extract values for the key `b` into another list

I could do the following

```
b = []
for item in a:
  b+= item['b']
```

this gives `[{'c': [1, 2, 3], 'd': 4}, {'c': [5, 6, 1], 'd': 7}, {'c': [2, 3, 4], 'd': 5}, {'c': [7, 6, 1], 'd': 8}]` which is fine.

I'm trying to learn list comprehension and wanted to know how this could be done. I tried the following 
`[ item['b'] for item in a]`. However that give a list of lists like below.

`[[{'c': [1, 2, 3], 'd': 4}, {'c': [5, 6, 1], 'd': 7}], [{'c': [2, 3, 4], 'd': 5}, {'c': [7, 6, 1], 'd': 8}]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try something like this, just keep in mind the outer loop would come first than the inner loop in the list comprehension

```
a = [{'a': 1, 'b': [{'c': [1, 2, 3], 'd': 4}, {'c': [5, 6, 1], 'd': 7}]}, {'a': 2, 'b': [{'c': [2, 3, 4], 'd': 5}, {'c': [7, 6, 1], 'd': 8}]}]

b = [ c for d in a for c in d['b']]
print(b)
```

OUTPUTS:

```
[{'c': [1, 2, 3], 'd': 4}, {'c': [5, 6, 1], 'd': 7}, {'c': [2, 3, 4], 'd': 5}, {'c': [7, 6, 1], 'd': 8}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following solutions. Solution at number (2) uses Python "itertools" module.

(1)

```
a = [{'a': 1, 'b': [{'c': [1, 2, 3], 'd': 4}, {'c': [5, 6, 1], 'd': 7}]}, {'a': 2, 'b': [{'c': [2, 3, 4], 'd': 5}, {'c': [7, 6, 1], 'd': 8}]}]

[ r for item in a for r in item['b']]
```

Output...

```
[{'c': [1, 2, 3], 'd': 4},
 {'c': [5, 6, 1], 'd': 7},
 {'c': [2, 3, 4], 'd': 5},
 {'c': [7, 6, 1], 'd': 8}]
```

(2)

```
a = [{'a': 1, 'b': [{'c': [1, 2, 3], 'd': 4}, {'c': [5, 6, 1], 'd': 7}]}, {'a': 2, 'b': [{'c': [2, 3, 4], 'd': 5}, {'c': [7, 6, 1], 'd': 8}]}]

import itertools
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([item['b'] for item in a]))
```

Output...

```
[{'c': [1, 2, 3], 'd': 4},
 {'c': [5, 6, 1], 'd': 7},
 {'c': [2, 3, 4], 'd': 5},
 {'c': [7, 6, 1], 'd': 8}]
```

Comment: Could you add description as well - finding it hard to comprehend.